# Floated box drops down when mousing over title text which expands

Tags: javascript, css

Please look at the screen shot.  How do I stop the property box from dropping down when I mouse over the title text and expands?

The wbesite url is http://luxurymarbellahomes.com/properties/

Here is the url for the screenshot.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/g6w70ibs3zk49zd/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-16%20at%2019.19.57.png?dl=0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap classes like visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block to isolate each row. After each row you can add a div like . Just tested in developer panel and it worked fine.

Comment: HI Andre, thanks for the reply.

I Added this and it seemt to have fixed the problem.


.properties-grid .span3 {
  height: 303px;
}

.properties-grid .row .property .title h2 a {
  font-size: 14px;
}

Comment: I do not recommend that. You'll get stuck at using maximum two lines for each title and every change of height on our box you will have to manually change the total height of the _.span3_ along with the bottom margin. However it is working properly.

Comment: How do I use visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block visible-lg-block?

Comment: In your case that each row always have 3 items you can make a change on your server side add a logic condition to test if the current index is multiple of 3, in that case print the HTML of the div with the class. Something like if(count % 3 == 0) print HTML .